# Find the sum of series.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

1000C50 +2.999C49 +3.998C48 +......... +51.950C0

$$\binom{1000}{50}+2\cdot \binom{999}{49}+3\cdot \binom{998}{48}+\cdots\cdots \cdots \cdots +51\cdot \binom{950}{0} $$

I tried to apply the pascal rule but failed as there are some numbers with the binomial coefficients, any hint would be helpful thanks.

Comment: What/which 'Pascal Rule'?

Comment: No ignore that, i was wrong in that. I am actually stuck on the terms like 1000C950 + 2.999C950+.....51.950C950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely combinatorial solution is possible, though it takes some experience to see it before knowing what the sum is. Let $S=\{0,1,\ldots,1001\}$. You want to count the subsets of $S$ having $952$ elements.

Suppose that $A$ is such a subset, and $k$ is its second-smallest element: there is exactly one member of $A$ smaller than $k$, and $950$ members of $A$ are larger than $k$. There are $k$ elements of $S$ smaller than $k$, so there are $k$ ways to choose the one member of $A$ that is smaller than $k$. There are $1001-k$ elements of $S$ bigger than $k$, so there are $\binom{1001-k}{950}$ ways to choose the $950$ elements of $A$ that are bigger than $k$. Thus, there are

$$k\binom{1001-k}{950}$$

$950$-element subsets of $S$ whose second-largest member is $k$. The smallest possible value of $k$ is $1$, since there has to be at least one member of $S$ smaller than $k$, and the largest is $51$, since there have to be at least $950$ members of $S$ larger than $k$, so the total number of $950$-element subsets of $S$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{51}k\binom{1001-k}{950}&=\sum_{k=1}^{50}k\binom{1001-k}{(1001-k)-950}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{51}k\binom{1001-k}{51-k}\\
&=\binom{1000}{50}+2\binom{999}{49}+3\binom{998}{48}+\ldots+50\binom{951}1+51\binom{950}0\;.
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand, there are $\binom{1002}{950}=\binom{1002}{52}$ subsets of $S$ with $950$ elements, so

$$\binom{1000}{50}+2\binom{999}{49}+3\binom{998}{48}+\ldots+50\binom{951}1+51\binom{950}0=\binom{1002}{952}\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

A shorter solution!
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^{50}(r+1)\binom {1000-r}{50-r}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{50}(r+1)\binom {1000-r}{950}\\
&=\sum_{s=950}^{1000}(1001-s)\binom s{950}&&(s=1000-r)\\
&=\sum_{s=950}^{1000}\sum_{t=s}^{1000}\binom s{950}\\
&=\sum_{t=950}^{1000}\sum_{s=950}^t\binom s{950}
&&(950\le s\le t\le 1000)\\
&=\sum_{t=950}^{1000}\binom {t+1}{951}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {1002}{952}=\binom {1002}{50}}
\end{align}$$

---

Previous answer below. 
$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^{50}(r+1)\binom {1000-r}{50-r}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{50}(r+1)\binom {1000-r}{950}\\
&=\sum_{s=950}^{1000}(1001-s)\binom s{950}&&(s=1000-r)\\
&=1002\sum_{s=950}^{1000}\binom s{950}-\sum_{s=950}^{1000}(s+1)\binom s{950}\\
&=1002\binom {1001}{951}-951\sum_{s=950}^{1000}\binom {s+1}{951}\\
&=952\binom {1002}{952}-951\binom {1002}{952}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom{1002}{952}=\binom {1002}{50}}\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you write 3rd step?

Comment: $1001-s=1002-(s+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Using $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$, we can write it as

$$\binom{1000}{950}+2\cdot \binom{999}{950}+3\cdot \binom{998}{950}+\cdots+51\cdot \binom{950}{950}\;,$$

which is same as finding the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in

$$(1+x)^{1000}+2(1+x)^{999}+3(1+x)^{998}+\cdots+51(1+x)^{950}\;.$$

Now let

$$S = (1+x)^{1000}+2(1+x)^{999}+3(1+x)^{998}+\cdots+51(1+x)^{950}\tag{1}\;,$$

so that

$$\frac{S}{1+x} = (1+x)^{999}+2(1+x)^{998}+3(1+x)^{997}+\cdots+51\cdot (1+x)^{949}\tag{2}\;.$$

Then subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$:

$$\begin{align*}
S-\frac{S}{1+x}&=\left(1-\frac1{1+x}\right)S=\frac{x}{1+x}S\\\\
&= \underbrace{(1+x)^{1000}+(1+x)^{999}+(1+x)^{998}+\cdots+(1+x)}_{\bf{Geometric\; Progression \; with \; common \; ratio\; (1+x) }}-51(1+x)^{949}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\frac{x}{1+x}\cdot S = (1+x)\cdot \frac{(1+x)^{1000}-1}{x}-51(1+x)^{949}\;,$$

and

$$S = \frac{(1+x)^{1002}}{x^2}-\frac{(1+x)^2}{x^2}-\frac{51(1+x)^{950}}{x^2}\;.$$

Thus, we want the coefficient of $x^{950}$ in

$$\frac{(1+x)^{1002}}{x^2}-\frac{(1+x)^2}{x^2}-\frac{51(1+x)^{950}}{x^2}\;,$$

which is the coefficient of  $x^{952}$ in $(1+x)^{1002}-(1+x)^2-51(1+x)^{950}$, and that is $\dbinom{1002}{952}$.

Comment: That sum actually is a AGP right?

Comment: I dont get how did you write 3rd step in which you wrote that $(1+x)^{100}$ stuff

Comment: Actually i have made mistake in that step.

Comment: Ohh, thats why i was wondering how did you write that